# Add value in DB table (Migration)

Tags: magento-1.9, database, migration

I need to insert a value into the database. The table already exists, just insert one more
[image]

And I need Insert `9 newcode newcode_title`
I created new file

> mysql4-upgrade-0.7.9-0.8.0.php

And it includes

```
<?php

$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

???????????
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('[YOUR TABLE]'),'new_column', array(
'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
'nullable'  => false,
'length'    => 255,
'after'     => null,
'comment'   => 'New column'
)); 
$installer->endSetup();
```

**EDIT:**

To insert data to your table you must create a model in your module and call the save action:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('modulename/modelname');
$model->setData($yourData);
$model->save();
```

Comment: Ty for answer.U add new column, but I need just a new value of the table. For example 
id picture_code picture_code_tittle
9  newcode    newcodetitle

Comment: if I have AI id, I shouldn't include it at the `$yourData`?

Comment: If it's autoincrement you don't have to add an id.